# Good reCAPTCHA downloading the audio gives a 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, accessibility, recaptcha

While testing we discovered that the download audio is going to a Google URL but giving a 404.

Has anyone else experienced this and if so how did you fix it?

Here is a video of what I am referring to.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lnf3enctrdpm3z4/404-google.mov?dl=0

Thank you for the help as I am stumped.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Were you able to figure out any fix for this?

Comment: Happens on their own demo site as well: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in their url. You need to remove `/audio.mp3`.

For the demo recaptcha:

- the provided url is https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload/audio.mp3?p=012345678ABC
- the right one is https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?p=012345678ABC

Comment: Any ways how to do it? Can't find this link in my code. Do I need to manipulate DOM?

Comment: this worked for me, the download capctcha changes for me every 1:55 - 2minutes